# AutoIT exe not working in selenium but works normally

Tags: selenium, autoit

I want to close the print window that is showing after submit a form. I used AutoIT to create an exe to close the window. It is working fine when running seperately but when I include it in selenium it is not working. Below I showing the code usind in selenium to call the AutoIT exe. Pls anyone sugggest a better alternative or help me to solve this issue
    // Close the print Window
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\eclipse-workspace\AutoITFiles\cancelPrintwindow.exe");

Comment: What is the err message you are getting. You have mentioned manually executing the autoIT exe works fine. Is the path you have mentioned in the code is correct?. In java we have to use single forward slash "/" or double backward slash "\\" while mentioning the sub directory.

Comment: I tried all combination of slashes. It is not showing any error message. But it is not executing the exe or closing the print window

Comment: Show us the code of your script. Try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your file path I assume you are using Java, do you have the correct AutoIt jar and dll files in your project?

You will need the following files as part of your project:

- AutoItX4Java.jar (or other version)
- jacob.jar
- AuotItX3.dll
- AutoItX3_64.dll